# Check if the element has text, if not add one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple table and I want to add specific text if an element is empty, so far my code looks like this:

```js
$("table").each(function (index, tableID) {
  $(tableID)
    .find("thead tr th")
    .each(function (index) {
      index += 1;
      $(tableID)
        .find("tbody tr td:nth-child(" + index + ")")
        .attr("data-title", $(this).text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>By Year</th>
        <th>TEAM</th>
        <th>GP</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>GSW</td>
        <td>6.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2016-17</th>
        <td>GSW</td>
        <td>6.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2015-16</th>
        <td>GSW</td>
        <td>6.1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

With this code am adding `data-title` and everything works fine, what am trying to achieve to add `-` when there is no data: so I modify my code:

```js
 $( "table" ).each( function( index, tableID ) {
     $( tableID ).find( "thead tr th" ).each( function( index ) {
         index += 1;
         $( tableID ).find( "tbody tr td:nth-child(" + index +  ")" ).attr( "data-title", $(this).text() );
         if ($("tbody tr td:nth-child(" + index +  ")" ).is(':empty')).append( "-" );
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>By Year</th>
        <th>TEAM</th>
        <th>GP</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>GSW</td>
        <td>6.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2016-17</th>
        <td>GSW</td>
        <td>6.1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2015-16</th>
        <td>GSW</td>
        <td>6.1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

This part of code where am adding `-` when table element is empty doesn't work, can anybody try to help me with this?

Comment: You have a question and a code. What's your actual problem?

Comment: @jabaa, this part of code where am adding - when table element is empty doesn't work

Comment: You can't call a method on a `if` condition: `if ($("tbody tr td:nth-child(" + index +  ")" ).is(':empty')).append`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement is not using valid syntax. You need the expression body after the `if` which contains the code to be executed. You cannot call a method from the `if` statement itself.

Try this:

```js
$("table").each(function(_, table) {
  $(table).find("thead tr th").each(function(i) {
    let $th = $(this);
    let $td = $(table).find("tbody tr td:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")");
    $td.attr("data-title", $th.text());
    if ($td.is(':empty')) {
      $td.append("-");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>By Year</th>
      <th>TEAM</th>
      <th>GP</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>GSW</td>
      <td>6.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2016-17</th>
      <td>GSW</td>
      <td>6.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2015-16</th>
      <td>GSW</td>
      <td>6.1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, it's worth noting that this code can be made more succinct with a single line of code:

```js
$('tbody td:empty').text('-');
```

The code you're using to loop through the `th`/`td` and add the `data` attribute seems almost entirely redundant as the `th` value can be read at the point of use.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the code a little. I found it easier to make the header data-title values an array i could reference each iteration. The '-' for empty values was just a ternary expression tacked on to the end of the jQuery chain:

```
$(this).attr("data-title", h[i]).text($(this).text() || "-");
```

```js
$("table").each(function() {
  let h = [], i = 0
  $("thead tr th").each(function() {
    h.push($(this).text());
  })
  $(this).find("tbody tr>*").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-title", h[i]).text($(this).text() || "-");
    i++;
    if (i >= h.length) i = 0
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>By Year</th>
      <th>TEAM</th>
      <th>GP</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>GSW</td>
      <td>6.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2016-17</th>
      <td>GSW</td>
      <td>6.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2015-16</th>
      <td>GSW</td>
      <td>6.1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```